# What are all these DLLs in the Castle ActiveRecord 3.0 beta?

Tags: castle-activerecord

This is a list of the DLLs in the Castle ActiveRecord 3.0 beta.  Does anyone know what all these do?  Which ones are required for a new project, and which ones are optional?

- Antlr3.Runtime.dll
- Castle.ActiveRecord.dll
- Castle.ActiveRecord.Web.dll
- Castle.Components.Validator.dll
- Castle.Core.dll
- Iesi.Collections.dll
- log4net.dll
- NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.dll
- NHibernate.dll
- NHibernate.Search.dll
- Remotion.Data.Linq.dll

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- **Antlr3.Runtime.dll**: used for HQL parsing in NHibernate
- **Remotion.Data.Linq.dll**: used as a base for the NHibernate Linq implementation.
- **Iesi.Collections.dll** implements ISet as always
- **log4net.dll**: logging as always
- **NHibernate.Search.dll**: integrates NHibernate with Lucene.net
- **Castle.Components.Validator.dll**: underlying validation implementation of ActiveRecord
- **Castle.Core.dll**: common stuff and DynamicProxy
- **Castle.ActiveRecord.Web.dll**: implements web session scopes. This was decoupled from **Castle.ActiveRecord.dll** to allow for framework client profiles.
- **NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.dll**: NHibernate proxy implementation that uses DynamicProxy.

Comment: Very nice.  What about the first two NHibernate ones listed?